# Word for any Word Processing document

Tags: computing

When sorting my files, I use the folder Presentation, Spreadsheet, Drawing and Database, because I use multiple Operating Systems.

But I don't have a word for Apple Pages / Microsoft Office Word / Libre Office Writer.

I don't like Word Processing, because it is two words, and I don't want to use Writer, because that is bias.

What single word covers all of these?

Comment: How about "document"?

Comment: I've used document for the containing folder (well, documents).

Comment: I'd go with "Writing".

Comment: @Greg What do you mean?

Comment: @Tim, human editors add marks to a manuscript which give directions about how the document is to be displayed in print.  Font, margins, etc.  When the formatting is done by a program instead of human typesetters, the text with added marks about desired display format is still said to have markup, and the various systems to do the formatting are called markup systems or markup languages.  Once the text has had markup added to it, ready to be displayed on screen or in print, it can be called "markup".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about calling your folder "Text."

Comment: Text may be the best...